# How to discriminate between null and zero length string in .NET?

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, is-empty

What is the most efficient way to discriminate between empty and null value? I want to:

1. evaluate `CStr(str)` to `True` when `str=""`, whereas
2. evaluate `CStr(str)` to `False` when `str=Nothing`

Comment: I'm not sure, is this a question?

Comment: Stack Overflow supports and encourages answering your own questions to help other users. The question is how to discriminate between  null and zero length string. Its usefull to avoid errors when passing strings to functions.

Comment: It is definetely not duplicate. The question is about discriminating CStr(nothing) from CStr("").

Comment: But if your requirement is still to be able to write something like `If(str.HasValue, str, "")`, the answer is still just `If(str,"")` which is what the various answers on that question all say.

Comment: No my requirement is to check if a string "" is passed as optional paramer to a function or nothing is passed. And because of this misconception I gained so much downvotes and a duplicate mark. It was this misleading example in my question... I corrected it.

Comment: No the 2 answers in this question (my answer and jmcilhinney's answer) do not say about If(). Both answers (my own included) say about String.Empty vs Nothing. Please remove the duplicate mark because this question is usefull for many people that do not know that `mystring is nothing` can discriminate these whereas `mystring = nothing` can not

Comment: Well, please edit your question to include a better *motivating example*, since you were originally basically asking for the VB equivalent of `??` and even following several edits, your motivating example is given as wanting to write `If(str.HasValue, str, "")`.

Comment: You are right. there is no need of this. I corrected it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function HasValue(s As String)
Return TypeOf (s) Is String
End Function
```

Slightly Better equivalent: (from answer of jmcilhinney)

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function HasValue(s As String)
Return  s IsNot Nothing
End Function
```

Also a benchmark of various methods on 10000 strings of various length:

**Function(x As String)**..............:**Total Time** (**rel Efficency** %)

TypeName(x) = "String".....................:0.850ms (17.1%)

VarType(x) = VariantType.String........:0.590ms  (24.6%)

TypeOf (x) Is String........................... :0.150ms   (96.7%)

x IsNot Nothing................................. :0.145ms  (100%)

Answer (score 2):

The `HasValue` property is for nullable value types.  For reference types (`String` is a reference type, as are all classes) you simply compare to `Nothing`:

```vb
If myString Is Nothing Then
```

Note the use of the `Is` operator.  That is for reference equality, while the `=` operator is for value equality.  Most types only support one or the other but `String` is one of the few types that support both because they both make sense.  Try this to see how they each behave:

```vb
Dim nullString As String = Nothing
Dim emptyString As String = String.Empty

If nullString Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("nullString Is Nothing")
End If

If nullString = Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("nullString = Nothing")
End If

If nullString Is String.Empty Then
    Console.WriteLine("nullString Is String.Empty")
End If

If nullString = String.Empty Then
    Console.WriteLine("nullString = String.Empty")
End If

If emptyString Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("emptyString Is Nothing")
End If

If emptyString = Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("emptyString = Nothing")
End If

If emptyString Is String.Empty Then
    Console.WriteLine("emptyString Is String.Empty")
End If

If emptyString = String.Empty Then
    Console.WriteLine("emptyString = String.Empty")
End If
```

Reference equality checks whether two references refer to the same object, while value equality checks whether two values are equivalent, regardless of what object they are.  `Nothing` and `String.Empty` are not the same thing in the context of reference equality because one is an object and one is no object, but they are considered equivalent in the context of value equality.

Comment: You are right:  myString Is Nothing is ok. My answer also works

Comment: I didn't know that `myString Is Nothing`returns different result from `myString = Nothing`